# My Macbook Air isn't allowing me to connect to my wifi?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

So this happened a while ago. I tried connecting my computer to my wifi here at home and thee was a message that never had appeared till now. It said:
 "NETGEAR" was previously joined as OPEN, not WPA Personal.

then it continues to ask me whether or not I would like to continue. I click join and seconds later a new message shows up where it says that it was unable to join and if I wanted to run diagnostics. This is all it says and it's driving me crazy. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @cascer1 this question is specifically about hardware so the [tag:mac] tag is more appropriate in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

What was the last thing you did? Did you go into the router and mess with any configurations? If not, someone could have gotten in and changed security settings. Or your router or computer simply needs a restart. Try the simple stuff first.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, someone else has logged into your router and added security. On the back of the router there is a small hole which is the reset button. Find a matchstick or something similar and press it in the reset hole for 8 seconds. This will reset your router back to factory settings and remove the security. I strongly advise setting a wpa2 password on the wireless so it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, **it may be that someone has reconfigured your router so that your wireless is no longer "unprotected"** (i.e. they have turned on WPA-Personal (not the best choice, but that's irrelevant - at least WPA2 if your router has it)). An open wireless (that's not protected elsewhere) is a bad thing.

Alternatively, **are you sure you have connected to the right wireless?** The network name (SSID) "NETGEAR" is very generic and if there is another "NETGEAR" network nearby then your device may be trying to connect to this and getting confused - much like walking up to a complete stranger thinking you recognise them and then realising it's not that person.

I would strongly recommend that you (or someone who is capable of) reconfigure your NETGEAR to an SSID that's unique. As an example, here in the UK, pretty much all ISPs who send out routers to their customers will have preconfigured the SSID and passphrase so that no two networks and passphrases are the same (this is debatable, but not for here).

As an example:

Sky: **SKY56157**

VirginMedia: **VM89C2468A**

BT: **BTHomeHub3-C1B7**